# What will be pricing model, when we resume trained model again in Google-AutoMl

Tags: google-cloud-vision, google-cloud-automl

I trained a model in Google-AutoMl, It took 24 hours to train for my 1500 images. I want to add more images and train again with new images.

1- Do I need to train that model again from start or I can resume that trained model?

2- If I resume the trained model, what will be the pricing model? It will charge again or it will charge only for new images?

Answer (score 0):

I look into the docs, forums and I can say that yes. You will have to train your model from the very beginning.

For now there is no way to train you model from previous ones.

The [Pricing](https://cloud.google.com/vision/automl/pricing#image_classification_prediction) will apply as usual:

FREE:

- 1 node hour per account for the first 10 models each month for free
- First 1,000 images prediction

PAID:

- Subsequent training hours are USD$20.00 per hour
- For 1,001–5,000,000 images*, the price is $3 per 1,000 images

Note that Google Cloud AutoML Vision stills on Beta stage and some features might be changed. Maybe will be able to train new models from pre-trained models. We can only wait now.

Also, remember:

**The accuracy of your model generally depends on how long you allow it to train and the quality of your training dataset.**

Hope this is helpful! :D